# How to merge rows in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, merge

I have a very big data frame (121920 obs of 7 variables). All variables are Factors. Data frame looks like this (with many more rows and different levels for each variable):

metaDATA:

```
         SITE        SOIL        TIME                      HOST TISSUE TEMP             MEDIA
MSHM1                  Sorkhe Gypsum Soil 2016-Winter          Acantholimon sp.   Leaf   23               PDA
MSHM2                  Sorkhe Gypsum Soil 2016-Winter          Acantholimon sp.   Leaf   23               PDA
MSHM3                  Sorkhe Gypsum Soil 2016-Winter          Acantholimon sp.   Leaf   23               PDA
MSHM4                  Sorkhe Gypsum Soil 2016-Winter          Acantholimon sp.   Leaf   23               PDA
MSHM5                  Sorkhe Gypsum Soil 2016-Winter          Acantholimon sp.   Leaf   23               PDA
MSHM6                  Sorkhe Gypsum Soil 2016-Winter          Acantholimon sp.   Leaf   23               PDA
MSHM7                  Sorkhe Gypsum Soil 2016-Winter          Acantholimon sp.   Leaf   23               PDA
MSHM8                  Sorkhe Gypsum Soil 2016-Winter          Acantholimon sp.   Leaf   23               PDA
```

I want to merge every 4 row into 1 row in a new data frame. Something like this:

```
MSHM1                  Sorkhe Gypsum Soil 2016-Winter          Acantholimon sp.   Leaf   23               PDA
MSHM4                  Sorkhe Gypsum Soil 2016-Winter          Acantholimon sp.   Leaf   23               PDA
MSHM8                  Sorkhe Gypsum Soil 2016-Winter          Acantholimon sp.   Leaf   23               PDA
MSHM12                  Sorkhe Gypsum Soil 2016-Winter          Acantholimon sp.   Leaf   23               PDA
```

Or only keep 1 of every 4 rows since they have the same level of each variable.

I tried :

```
S1<-seq(1,121920,4)
S2<-seq(4,121920,4)
D<-matrix(0,length(S1),7)
for (i in 1:length(S1)) {
  D[i,1]<-noquote(paste(metaDATA[S1[i]:S2[i],1]))
  D[i,2]<-noquote(paste(metaDATA[S1[i]:S2[i],2]))
  D[i,3]<-noquote(paste(metaDATA[S1[i]:S2[i],3]))
  D[i,4]<-noquote(paste(metaDATA[S1[i]:S2[i],4]))
  D[i,5]<-noquote(paste(metaDATA[S1[i]:S2[i],5]))
  D[i,6]<-noquote(paste(metaDATA[S1[i]:S2[i],6]))
  D[i,7]<-noquote(paste(metaDATA[S1[i]:S2[i],7]))
  }
```

But this did not work and I got this error:

```
Error in D[i, 6] <- noquote(paste(metaDATA[S1[i]:S2[i], 6])) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Comment: Do you care if the rows are identical, or you you just want to delete all rows except for every 4th row? And you say you want to merge rows, but in your example, you seem to just be deleting rows. The remaining rows remain the same

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your date is named `df`, try

```
newdf <- df[ c(TRUE, rep(FALSE,3) ), ]
```

keeps the first row, skips 3, keeps the fifth row, skips 3, etc...

Comment: Thanks. I modified the code and it worked. See my own answer to the question if interested.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `%%` (modulo) to create the row indices for subsetting:

```
D <- df[(1:nrow(df)%%4) == 1, ]
```

**Output:**

```
> (1:nrow(mtcars)%%4)
 [1] 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0

> mtcars[(1:nrow(mtcars)%%4)==1,]
                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 450SL        17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Toyota Corona     21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Pontiac Firebird  19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Ford Pantera L    15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your problem, let's say you want to take 1 row after skipping 3 rows

```
take = 1
skip = 3

total = nrow(df)
reps = total %/% (skip + take)
index = rep(0:(reps-1), each = take) * (skip + take) + 1
```

The value of index is

```
# Assuming nrow(df) = 100 
[1]  1  5  9 13 17 21 25 29 33 37 41 45 49 53 57 61 65 69 73 77 81 85 89 93 97
```

Now, you can get your subset:

```
subset = df[index, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

or you just create a vector to index the rows that you want to extract

```
index_<-seq(1, nrow(df), by = 4)
df[index_,]
```

Answer (score 0):

With help from a friend, I found a code which worked as I wanted.
Here is the code that I used:

```
S1<-seq(1,121920,4)
S2<-seq(4,121920,4)
D<-matrix(0,length(S1),7)
for (i in 1:length(S1)) {
  D[i,1]<-noquote(paste(data[S2[i],1]))
  D[i,2]<-noquote(paste(data[S2[i],2]))
  D[i,3]<-noquote(paste(data[S2[i],3]))
  D[i,4]<-noquote(paste(data[S2[i],4]))
  D[i,5]<-noquote(paste(data[S2[i],5]))
  D[i,6]<-noquote(paste(data[S2[i],6]))
  D[i,7]<-noquote(paste(data[S2[i],7]))
  }
```

This kept every 4th row of my original data frame and gave me a new matrix. 
Thanks.